# return IDs with lowest rank for a grouping variable

Tags: mysql

For each ID number, I need to group ID numbers by class values, using the lowest rank when there are duplicate class values...I have tried several joins with no success. Would appreciate a VERY brief description for any code suggested. Thanks!

Table Structure:

```
ID  Rank    Class
A   1       x
A   2       x
A   3       y
A   4       y
B   1       x
B   2       x
B   3       y
B   4       y
```

Desired Result:

```
ID  Rank    Class
A   1       x
A   3       y
B   1       x
B   3       y
```

Comment: Joins you say, which joins would those be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an aggregate function `MIN()` with a `GROUP BY` the `id` and `class`:

```
select id, min(rank) as MinRank, class
from yourtable
group by id, class
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14381/2)

```
| ID | MinRank | CLASS |
--------------------------
|  A |       1 |     x |
|  A |       3 |     y |
|  B |       1 |     x |
|  B |       3 |     y |
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the SQL demo link! I figured this was very straightforward. The other query examples I saw seemed inordinately inefficient.

Comment: @user996544 happy to help.  Yes sql fiddle is a great tool when posting to these sites

Comment: @user996544    Suppose that the table contains several data columns to the right of the Class column. The problem with this query is that it doesn't seem to pick the correct record for the data columns following. It seems to me that I need to do a join with the orignal table and the query you suggested to get the extra data columns?

Comment: You can use this query as a subquery and then join back to your main table.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) with [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) as aggregate function would do it.

```
SELECT `ID`, 
       Min(`Rank`) AS `Rank`, 
       `Class` 
FROM   tbl1 
GROUP  BY `ID`, 
          `Class`
```